# Which partitions should I delete on Windows 10 to get rid of my Ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

My ultimate goal is to remove all the Ubuntu partitions, but I can't tell which ones are Ubuntu partitions…

Windows partitions screenshot:

[image: Windows partitions screenshot]

Ubuntu screenshot 1:

[image: Ubuntu screenshot 1]

Ubuntu screenshot 2:

[image: Ubuntu screenshot 2]

Comment: I see 86 GB of unallocated space that follows your system partition and can almost guarantee you that’s the space that was created when you shrunk the partition

Comment: Thanks, I see that now but I'm confused why it doesn't show up on the list above with the other partitions. Also it's still unclear where Ubuntu is installed so that I know what partition to try deleting. I thought I created 100GB of partition space for Ubuntu but maybe that got botched and it's installed on one of the small partitions seen in the Windows list.

Comment: It’s unallocated thus has no file system, which means, Ubuntu wasn’t installed on that particular partition.  Your Ubuntu install is located on approximately 20 GB partition

Comment: Sorry, my order of events was actually: Partition 100GB of space, install Ubuntu (not sure if it got successfully placed on that partition), use Ubuntu and get told that I'm out of space in a very short amount of time, come back to Windows and check partitions, can't tell what are Ubuntu partitions, create a new 86GB partition as a test, write question on Superuser in confusion. I'm actually using Ubuntu right now so it was installed somewhere. It's just that I can't tell where it was installed, but wherever it was installed it doesn't have enough space for what I intended to do. New to Ubuntu

Comment: It’s on a 19.6 GB partition, which if Ubuntu uses base 2 instead of base 10 likely is the 18.6 GB partition (your question is too confusing to follow/decode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you boot into a linux OS, the partition that is mounted as "/" will be
the linux install partition. In your case, that would be "sda12", which usually means the 13th partition on the first disk. You should not use the Windows Disk Management snap-in to garner information on your disks and volumes, as it is buggy and unreliable. Also, installing linux software as snap packages results in a grotesque wastage of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a partition that is in use , boot to live ubuntu usb and use gnome disks to identify partitions, the press the dash to remove it.Dont touch efi and ntfs partitions